# Python Running out of memory while using Yield

Tags: python

Here's the story:

I have a 765GB text file which has to be parsed. Below, I've included the relevant code to do so:

```
def ingest(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as food:
        for line in food:
            yield line
```

After processing about 56GB I get a `KILLED` statement, indicating the process ran out of memory. A quick `STRACE` shows that the module dies while running the function shown above. It also shows each line being read.

Herein lies my confusion. On the one hand, the `for` loop wants to iterate through all of its elements. On the other, the `yield` statement should force lazy evaluation of the iterable, bringing forth each element when `next()/__next__` is called. Or so I thought.

Why, in this case, does the function attempt to read the lines all at once; instead of reading one by one?

And how can I solve this particular issue?

Comment: How are you calling this function?

Comment: There could be other parts in your code that hog up memory which ultimately caused this allocation to fail. Or that your input file has a line that did not terminate.

Comment: Are you keeping a reference to the lines anywhere in your code?

Comment: I don't know if this is the case but if you are reading it in binary format is the file still split into lines? Maybe you are reading one massive line of data

Comment: What you thought is pretty much correct. (It may actually be buffering more than just a line at a time, but only a few KB, so you can ignore that.) So the problem is most likely in the _caller_ to this function. For a trivial example, if you write `stuff = [line.strip().split(',') for line in ingest(filename)]`, then it doesn't matter that `ingest` is lazy, because you're driving it to read the entire file and store the parsed results in a list.

Comment: @vicg: Yes, it is still split into lines… but that could be the problem. A big hunk of binary data could theoretically go 56GB without a single `\n` byte, in which case that would all be one giant line.

Comment: Meanwhile, why are you writing this code? The file is already a lazy iterable of lines; you're trying to wrap it up in a lazy iterable of lines that acts exactly like the file itself, but with a bit of extra overhead. What's the point in that?

Comment: Add a print to your code, and you'd probably be more enlightened:

`def ingest(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as food:
        for line in food:
            print line;  
            yield line`

Comment: @IsmailBadawi: The module itself is being called from the command line. The function is the first statement in main().
@metatoaster: The `STRACE` shows that no other parts of the code are executing. The function above is both defined first and called first.
@PadraicCunningham: No.
@abarnert & @vicg: The file indeed contains new lines. Working with a `head` of 10 million lines (~4.7GB), the function (and module) works just fine; running in ~10 seconds. 
@boardrider : What would a print statement tell me that `STRACE` wouldn't?

Comment: Please edit your post to show the code calling this method and using the results from it. Maybe you think it's obvious, but far as I can see you haven't even hinted at what this other code is and does. It is that code, not the code you have posted, that is causing your problem.